# Load Chrome Extensions in ElectronJS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

Could anyone please tell me how to inject my js via Chrome Extensions in ElectronJS? I have an extension (manifest v2) that works in Chrome. It loads in electron (I see an object after await loadExtension() call), but its code is not inserted (I don't see a markup change and nothing in dev tools console)

If you can provide a sample extension that works (possibly code in ElectronJS also), that would be super perfect! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I called the loadExtension() after the loadURL().